# Difference between Interoperability and Interaction

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Is there any difference between those two terms: 'Interaction' and 'Interoperability'?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please indicate which dictionaries you have consulted, and if their definitions are inadequate, please why and in what context you find them inadequate. I encourage you to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance on how to ask answerable questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Interoperability* is the ability to operate (work) together. And *interaction* is the actual process happening between two or more subjects when they interact.

See [interoperability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperability) and [interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction) for Wikipedia descriptions.

Answer (score -1):

Interoperability describes the extent to which systems and devices can exchange data, and interpret that shared data. For two systems to be interoperable, they must be able to exchange data and subsequently present that data such that it can be understood by a user.

Interaction is a kind of action that occurs as two or more objects have an effect upon one another like two or more people talking to each other or communicate to each other.

Comment: Please [source your](http://www.himss.org/library/interoperability-standards/what-is) [copy-and-paste jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction).